# why android L has /system/app/apkname/apkname.apk folder structure

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop

I was checking sytem/aap folder structure in Android L and realized that it has a new folder structure. It has introduced a new folder with apt name between app and apt. So new folder is like /system/app/test/test.apk

I was wondering what is advantage of this new folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

For convenience I presume. The folder "apkname" may contain more than just the APK file (like .so files in lib folder)